# Laravel Custom Admin Login is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have been developing a Laravel Auth system where there is a admin panel I had to create a custom admin authentication system. After after going through all the steps the login system is not working. After submitting the login form it redirect me to the same login page again instead of redirecting to the dashboard page. I am giving details of my whole system.

Let me know if anyone could help.

**Admin Model**

```
    namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Admin DB Migrations**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

**Config\Auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

   

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    
    
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
       

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
       
    ],

    

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
       
    ],

   

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**Login.Blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('pagetitle', 'Admin-Login')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card raleway">
                <div class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i> &nbsp;{{ __('Admin Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top:10%;padding-bottom:10%;">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route($loginRoute) }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>
                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route($forgotPasswordRoute) }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                       
                    </form>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
   /**
     * Show the login form.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login',[
           
            'loginRoute' => 'admin.login',
            'forgotPasswordRoute' => 'admin.password.request',
        ]);
    }
     
    /**
     * Login the admin.
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request);
    
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->filled('remember'))){
            //Authentication passed...
            return redirect()
                ->intended(route('admin.dashboard'))
                ->with('status','You are Logged in as Admin!');
        }
    
        //Authentication failed...
        return $this->loginFailed();
    }

    /**
     * Logout the admin.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect()
            ->route('login')
            ->with('status','Admin has been logged out!');
    }

    /**
     * Validate the form data.
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return 
     */
    private function validator(Request $request)
    {
     //validation rules.
    $rules = [
        'email'    => 'required|email|exists:admins|min:5|max:191',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:4|max:255',
    ];

    //custom validation error messages.
    $messages = [
        'email.exists' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
    ];

    //validate the request.
    $request->validate($rules,$messages);
    }

    /**
     * Redirect back after a failed login.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    private function loginFailed()
    {
        return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->withInput()
        ->with('error','Login failed, please try again!');
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
      
        Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');

    Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function(){
        
        //Login Routes
        Route::get('/login',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\LoginController::class,'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
        Route::post('/login',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\LoginController::class,'login']);
        Route::post('/logout',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\LoginController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');

    
       
    
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is happening for `Constructor`

Comment: Can you please tell me  in detailed ?

Comment: is there anything in `$errors` or `$error` (you use `error` in the failed response) in the login view? ... if validation fails or authentication fails you have this setup to redirect back to the login view

Comment: error','Login failed, please try again!'  this is on the $error

Comment: then you failed to login ... also if you always want them to go to the dashboard do not use `intended`

Comment: I have tried with redirected method instead of intended still does not work

Comment: You are not getting any error now?

Comment: same error $error','Login failed, please try again!'

Comment: which means the login failed, so of course it isn't going to send you to the `dashboard` since you are not logged in

Comment: Why its failing, where is the problem in my code I just wanted to know that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

So I have solved my problem today.
The problem was occurring because of the below function in my AdminDashboardController.php

```
/**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

After removing it. Everything working fine now.